# FormGroup.value no getting the value

Tags: angular, angular9

if i console.log(this.invoiceForm), inside formgroup the value is showing some value,but when i console.log(this.invoiceForm.value), is no getting the formGroup value.

Code: 
[image]

Console log 
[image]

May I know what is the difference between .value and without .value?

Comment: There is probably no value in the first log either, but it gets updated by reference.

Comment: how to know that? because it confuses me, any document i can read about this issue?

Comment: I suggest you use `OnChanges` - if I am correct you will get invoiceForm AFTER onInit. Btw take a look at ControlValueAccessor if you are separating form to components.

Comment: ok, I will try `OnChanges`. I'm trying to get the value from the API return and assign the value into the invoiceForm and pass it to child components. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole formGroup value, outside the form, you can try this

```
const formValue = this.invoiceForm.getRawValue();
```

This will generate a keyValue pair for all the controls as Keys and their values as values.